# Rename a data frame using the value of a string?

Tags: r

Is there a way to rename a data frame using the value of a string?

I'm trying to write a function in [R] that takes a vector of values, operates over them, and (among other things) returns a data frame to the global environment using the <<- operator. I'd like the name of this data frame to reflect the name of the vector used to create it.

Ideally the code would look something like this:

```
my.func <- function(vector.in){

# ... Operations over vector.in ... #

data.out <- data.frame(x1 = ...)
new.name <- paste("data.out", deparse(substitute(vector.in)), sep="_")

#Change the name of data.out to the value of the string new.name
changename(data.out, new.name)

#Export the newly named object to the global environment
new.name <<- new.name

# ... More operations ... #

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the name of the data frame, the name of a variable it is assigned to?  Why not just return the data frame from the function?  I can't find documentation for your `changename` function, `?changename` doesn't return anything for me.

Comment: I'm curious though, what's the common use case for this sort of thing?

Comment: The function I'm writing is designed to recode categorical data in a very specific way, and to return a formula object that can be included in a call to glm(). I'd like to be able to simply point to an existing vector of data and run a function that both (a) creates a "matrix" of coded predictors, and (b) provides a compact way to include the resulting variables (sometimes upwards of 200 of them) into a regression equation. The critical problem is that I need to do this for several variables simultaneously, and thus need my "matricies" to automatically be assigned different names.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the forum for pure coding questions. But I use the assign function for this type of stuff

```
# ... Operations over vector.in ... #
new.name <- paste("data.out", deparse(substitute(vector.in)), sep="_")
assign(new.name,data.frame(x1 = ...))
ls() #you should see new.name
which(ls()==new.name) #this will return an integer
```

I would not put this inside a function because the assignment will be done inside the environment of that function only.  Anyway I am sure there is more formal ways but this works well for me

Comment: Looks like you can pass an environment argument `envir` to assign, so you can use assign in local scope to make a variable assignment in a global scope.

Comment: @MatthewDrury yes I think you are correct, however, I know from experience that environment assignment can get tricky in R, or any language for that matter. In general I prefer not to make assignments across environments if I can avoid it...but that's just my personal preference...and what you mentioned is certainty doable

Comment: Agreed.  It seems better to just return the data frame than `<<-`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses @MatthewDrury. assign() seems to be exactly the function I was looking for. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `<<-` operator and its brethren are best avoided, but if you must:

```
myfun <- function(objname){assign(objname,3L,envir=.GlobalEnv)}
```

assigns `3` to the object with the name passed. For example,

```
myfun("gah")
gah
# [1] 3
```